# Difference between Internal terminal, External terminal and Standard output in Netbeans

Tags: c, netbeans, console

I just got to know there are multiple consoles in Netbeans when working on a C-program. Please let me know what are the differences between them and when will they be used. Please see the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Internal or standard could be the traditional console windows which normally netbeans uses . External creates a new window for I/o. Though I am not clear on them yet .

Comment: Run programs on all three and you will know . Way to find out :)

Answer (score 2):

External uses a separate stand-alone program to run your application. 
The program can be selected on the next line labeled "External Terminal Type".

On linux the options are GnomeTerminal and XTerm.

If you are familiar with these programs you could customize them more than the built-in terminal, or perhaps you just prefer to have a separate re-sizeable window. If your code is using libraries like curses for screen editing then you may want to test inside these programs.  If your just logging debug messages to standard out and reading one line at a time from standard in, then it probably doesn't matter.

Standard Output and Internal Terminal both run in  windows built-in to netbeans, usually in the bottom right corner. I am not clear on the differences, although it effects the background color for me.

Here is a reference from the Netbeans site titled "TerminalEmulator":
http://wiki.netbeans.org/TerminalEmulator